# Stata ANOVA: factor variables may not contain noninteger values

Tags: stata, anova

I have an outcome variable `y` and person id `id` like following:

```
y            id
-.2900997   19137
.2731551    19143
-.0283341   3.000e+09
.3288157    599
1.045171    2746
.4293538    2746
```

I am just running a simple command `anova y id` but get an error message: `id:  factor variables may not contain noninteger values`.

However, the `id` variable is all integers. The only reason I can think of may be the scientific values such as `3.000e+09`. So I change the format using `format id %012.0f` so they all look like integers now:

```
y            id
-.2900997   000000019137
.2731551    000000019143
-.0283341   300000000005
.3288157    000000000599
1.045171    000000002746
.4293538    000000002746
```

However, when I run anova again, the same error occurs.

In addition, `oneway y id` works without any problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you!!

Comment: Try `egen newid = group(id), label` and use that variable.

Comment: Thank you!! This solves the problem. May I ask what's the logic behind it? Like is there a reason Stata doesn't treat integer as integer in the original data?

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are documented in `help fvvarlist`.

> Categorical variables to which factor-variable operators are applied
> must contain nonnegative integers with values in the range 0 to
> 32,740, inclusive.

Accordingly, try mapping your identifiers to new identifiers 1 up:

```
egen newid = group(id), label
```